# Python for() loop with math operators

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-3.x

Say I have a list of numbers such as:

`my_list = [1, 17, 2]`

And I wanted to add those together.  I know I can use `print(sum(my_list))`.  However I wanted to see if there was another way of doing so, so I tried the following:

```
b = len(my_list)
for m in range(my_list[0], my_list[b-1]):
    m += m
    print(m)
```

I am sure something like this should work, but I am obviously doing it wrong.  The output of this is `2`.  After I tried:

```
result = 0
b = len(my_list)
for m in range(my_list[0], my_list[b-1]):
    result = result + m
    print(result)
```

This outputs `1`.

Please explain what I am doing wrong and how I can correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should put a correct range: 0..2 in your case (since your list items' indexes starts from 0 and has 2 items)

```
  for i in range(0, b):
      result = result + my_list[i];
```

Or if you prefer "for each" style you should itterate by list you are summing:

```
  for m in my_list:
      result = result + m;
```

Finally if you want to print a final sum only you should correct print indent:

```
  for m in my_list:
      result = result + m;

  print(result)  # <- mind indent
```

Wrapping up:

```
  my_list = [1, 17, 2]

  result = 0

  for m in my_list:
      result = result + m;

  print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for the multiple examples, this helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using range function defining range between 1 and 2. The only data generated in m is 1 hence result is 1.

In Python, you can iterate over the elements of a sequence directly:

```
m = [1, 17, 2]
res = 0
for i in m:
    res += i
print res
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from operator import add

my_list = [1, 17, 2]
result=reduce(add, my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import functools

print(functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, my_list))
```

Comment: I appreciate the response and I'll note this for future reference. I haven't gotten to functools yet, thank you though.

Comment: if you're familiar with reduce in python 2.x, it's the same in python 3.x but they wrap it in functools module

Comment: I have been programming for about a week now.  I have learned a lot, struggled here and there, but have overcome every obstacle thus far.  Hoping I can continue that way.  It is a lot of fun!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
my_list = [1, 17, 2]
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the values from my_list you can use this syntax:

```
for m in my_list:
    print m
```

If you use range it will give you a range from 1 ( first value of your list ) to 2 (length of your list -1)

To add the values of your list you can try this code:

```
out = 0
for m in my_list:
   out = out + m
print(out)
```